# str_replace doesn't replace accurately

Tags: php, str-replace

I am working on a multilingual wordpress website where I need to append a loclale in all internal url in a web page.

So I have all of the content of the webpage in the $content variable. now

```
preg_match_all( '/<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=([\"\'])(.*?)\1/', $content, $matches );

$localized_url_arr = [];
$url_arr           = [];
if ( ! empty( $matches[2] ) ) {
    $current_locale = get_current_locale();

    foreach ( $matches[2] as $url ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/si', $url ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $new_url = add_locale_to_url( $url, $current_locale ); // this is adding locale to url eg => www.example.com --> www.example.com/us for us locale
        if ( $new_url !== $url ) {
            $localized_url_arr[] = [
                $url => $new_url
            ];
        }
    }
}  

$arr  = array_merge(...$localized_url_arr);

$content = str_replace( array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $content );
```

now Ideally this function should replace those to those urls which dosen;t have a locale in them. but it is appending locale in all the url, however the `$arr` has only those urls which needs to be appended with a locale but my str_replace is appending all urls that we have in matches[2] array.

Comment: Please post some sample data, the desired result, and what you're getting instead.

Comment: FYI you can use `strtr()` to do all the replacements in an associative array.

Comment: And instead of pushing onto a 2-dimensional array, you could just make the associative array directly in the loop. `$arr[$url] = $new_url;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace `www.example.com` with `www.example.com/us`, it will replace it anywhere it appears, even if there's already `/us` after it.

You can use a regular expression with a negative lookahead to replace a string only if it's not followed by some other pattern.

```
preg_match_all( '/<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=([\"\'])(.*?)\1/', $content, $matches );

$localized_url_arr = [];
if ( ! empty( $matches[2] ) ) {
    $current_locale = get_current_locale();

    foreach ( $matches[2] as $url ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/si', $url ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $new_url = add_locale_to_url( $url, $current_locale ); // this is adding locale to url eg => www.example.com --> www.example.com/us for us locale
        $url_pattern = "#$url(?!/us/#si";
        if ( $new_url !== $url ) {
            $localized_url_arr[$url] = $new_url
        }
    }

    $content = preg_replace(array_keys($localized_url_arr), array_values($localized_url_arr), $content );

}
```

The regular expression matches each URL unless it's followed by `/us/`, and will replace it with `$new_url`.

Comment: no this is for skipping the emails only, if there is an email so we wont add a locale to it

Comment: I want to replace all the $url with $new_url if they are not same, but it is also replace for those which are same as well, I mean it's replacing for those links also which are not in ```localized_url_arr``` array

Comment: The basic problem is that if you want to replace `xxx` with `xxx/yyy`, it will match the `xxx` that's already followed by `/yyy`. The only way to prevent that is to use a regular expression that rejects `/yyy`.

Comment: ahh ok got u, now my concern is i have urls like example.com/us/contact, example.com/about and example.com/us/info and I want it to be replaced like example.com/us/contact, example.com/us/about and example.com/us/info . but right now it gives me this example.com/us/us/contact, example.com/us/about and example.com/us/us/info

Comment: how can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `/us/` explicitly in the negative lookahead, since the `if` statement regexp is not the same pattern you're trying to exclude.